Android emulator won't start and I can't delete the emulator lock files as suggested
I'm building an android app on android studio 2024.2.1.  But I am unable to start any emulators.  I have tried clearing caches and restarting everything including my PC.
I've tried to delete the .lock files under the .avd but my powershell tells me it can't delete those files because another process is using them.
But when I run Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.Modules.FileName -icontains "multiinstance.lock" } | select Name, ID as well as several other commands it returns nothing so it appears that no other process are using those files.
I've spent all at this and I'm at a loss.  How do I delete this lock emulator lock files or otherwise get my emulators to start?

If you enter in Safety Mode you can delete this folder. Happens with me and worked. Also pea attention with non ASCII character in the emulator path.

Use Handle search in MS Sysinternals ProcessExplorer to identify the processes that keep the files open and kill them. I assume those processes are stalled invisible emulator processes .

Thanks @AlexandreB. safe mode allowed me to delete the problem files.

I put that information as Answer to you  set it up and help others users.

If you enter in Safety Mode you can delete this folder.
Also pay attention to non-ASCII characters in the emulator path.
To start your Mac in safe mode, you can press and hold the Shift key while your Mac starts up
To start in Windows Hold down the F8 key while the computer is booting up (there are some variations here)

Try using your phone as an emulator, such as with Expo Go. That might be a temporary solution.

I have been using a physical device, but in this specific case the tests won't run on my physical device so I need the emulator working.
